# Alter javascript function after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropzone

I am a very bad Js coder, learning at the moment. Though I have to probem I would like to fix.

I have a Dropzone snippet on my page with local setup that looks like :

```
var AUTH_TOKEN=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone",{
        url: "<%= photographe_photographephotos_path(@photographe.hashed_id) %>",
        // url: "<%= photographe_path(@photographe.hashed_id) %>",
        // method: "patch",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        autoDiscover: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        // clickable: false,
        parallelUploads: <%= @slots_libres %>,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        maxFiles: <%= @slots_libres %>,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png',
        params:{
            'authenticity_token':  AUTH_TOKEN
        },
        successmultiple: function(data,response){
            $('#msgBoard').append(response.message).addClass("alert alert-success");
            $('#msgBoard').delay(2000).fadeOut();
            $('#fileslist').val(response.filesList);
            $('#photographedit').off('submit').submit();
        }
    });
    $('#photographedit').submit(function(e){
        if(myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0){
            e.preventDefault();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        }
    });
```

It works well.

It allows to upload images to a certain limit. This limit is implemented through this line :

```
maxFiles: <%= @slots_libres %>,
```

`@slots_libres` is the number of possible pictures being uploaded (computed in ruby). This server side value just shows as plain text in html/Js, like :

```
maxFiles: 6,
```

**Now here is my problem:**

The user has the ability to delete pictures through Ajax on the fly. Without reloading page `maxFiles` value is never changed then not allowing one extra picture to be uploaded.

And I don't know what Javascript I should add to the above Js code in order to alter this very value ? (I know how to manipulate DOM through Ajax, but altering a currently running function is something I don't know how to do yet...)

Comment: Use some ajax to get the current count, then update it perhaps?> `myDropzone.maxFiles = currentcount;` Note I don't have intimate knowledge of the snippet but maybe this will get you started.

Comment: You can also check the currentcount in server side and return a error response or update maxFiles in the ajax response.

Comment: thanks for your answers but it does not seem to work with `myDropzone.maxFiles = <%= @newfreeslots %>;` eventhough I am sure `@newfreeslots` hold the correct value (I update it in html too to let the user know how many he can update)

Comment: Ok I have removed the maxfiles limitation for now and it works all good. Will revert to it later and se why it doesnt accept my new value